# How to call a GET method which accepts same parameter type in web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Model called Issues which have Id and severity attributes which are integers and an Issue Controller which should handle GET requests and return All Issues and by Severity. Since Dotnet API doesn't support the same parameter type such as int, how do I do this?

I tried using different method names such as `Get()` and `GetBySeverity(int severity)` but ambiguous exception arose.

this is my controller

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class IssuesController : ControllerBase
{   

    [HttpGet(Name="issues")]
    public IEnumerable<Issue> GetAllIssues() {
            IssueService service = new IssueService();
            return service.GetIssues();
}

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Issue> GetBySeverity([FromQuery(Name="severity")]int severity)
    {
        IssueService service = new IssueService();
        return service.GetIssuesBySeverity(severity);

    }


}
```

these are the apis which i want to develop
`/api/issues/` 
  and 
`/api/issues/?severity=1`

Comment: Take a look at the comment above your Get method try calling it this way.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
//GET api/issues/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Issue GetByRoute([FromRoute(Name="id")] int id)
{
    IssueService service = new IssueService();
    return service.GetIssueById(id);
}   


[HttpGet()]
public Issue GetByQuery([FromQuery(Name="severity")] int severityId)
{
   IssueService service = new IssueService();
   return service.GetIssueById(severityId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ambiguous reference because both actions are `HttpGet` and the routing engine cannot decide which route to take or which route you meant.

Web Api controllers route using HttpVerbs rather than the action/method name (like MVC).

I would use [Attribute routing with Http[Verb] attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing-with-httpverb-attributes).  This uses `Route("myroute")` to define the route.

```
// GET api/issues/severity/5
[Route("severity/{severity}")]
[HttpGet()]
public IEnumerable<Issue> GetBySeverity(int severity)
{
    IssueService service = new IssueService();
    return service.GetIssuesBySeverity(severity);
}

// GET api/issues/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Issue Get(int id)
{
    IssueService service = new IssueService();
    return service.GetIssueById(id);
}
```

The above methods would route to `api/issues/1` and `api/issues/severity/1`.  If you want to map using query param rather than url param then the below should work:

```
// GET api/issues/severity?severity=5
[HttpGet("severity")]
public IEnumerable<Issue> GetBySeverity([FromQuery] int severity)
{
    IssueService service = new IssueService();
    return service.GetIssuesBySeverity(severity);
}

// GET api/issues?id=5
[HttpGet()]
public Issue Get([FromQuery] int id)
{
    IssueService service = new IssueService();
    return service.GetIssueById(id);
}
```

The above actions will route to `api/issues?id=1` and `api/issues/severity?severity=1`

Comment: i have updated the question you can a have a look, the problem is with GetAllIssues and GetBySeverity and it persists even when i add Name tag. i think its because they have same return type.

Comment: The controller doesn't know which action to use.  You need to specify a different route. Why not use `api/issue/severity/1` to get issues by severity?  If you want to do that then add `Route("severity/{severity}")` above the action.  The name parameter won't do anything, `[Route()]` is what you want to use. Otherwise, refactor your methods into one, you may need additional arguments to do that. @mdr